# error in locked 'vector' file

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error occurring in the 'vector' class, as in, the class which you access when you #include < vector >

the error I get mostly is:

Error   1   error C2259: 'Gun' : cannot instantiate abstract class

This class, Gun, is indeed abstract, but I have checked the code and in no place is there an instance of this trying to be created. What there is, is a few definitions of

vector< Gun > blah;

as class instance members which will be populated by derived classes so that I may use their polymorphic functions.

Although I cannot access the vector class to change it (and even if I could I wouldn't want to) I can see what part of it's code the error is occurring on:

the first line of this block:

```
void resize(size_type _Newsize, _Ty _Val)
    {   // determine new length, padding with _Val elements as needed
    if (size() < _Newsize)
        _Insert_n(end(), _Newsize - size(), _Val);
    else if (_Newsize < size())
        erase(begin() + _Newsize, end());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector declared as

```
std::vector<Gun>
```

will contain only Gun objects. If you try to place an instance derived from Gun, then the object will be sliced down to its Gun part, which is abstract. You would need to store pointers to dynamically allocated copies in the vector, like

```
std::vector<Gun*>
```

To spare yourself the dereferencing and deleting logic, use boost's pointer containers:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
boost::ptr_vector<Gun>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't because when you do vector you are creating objects of that type if you are 
inherting which i figured you need to do

```
 Ak47 *gun1 = new Ak47(ammo);
 vector<Gun*> guns;
 guns[0]=&*gun1;
```

Comment: "guns.push_back(gun1);" is safer and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is holding by-value objects, so Gun objects will get instantiated, that's why you get an error.